What command do I use to run my node backend?
I have a MERN stack application from about a year ago, and I am trying to run it on my local again, but can't seem to remember what commands I used.
I managed to get the React frontend running on localhost:3000 using npm start, but haven't been able to get the backend to run.
Here is my package.json:
  "name": "investingideas",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^4.3.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1298.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "dompurify": "^2.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.8.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
}

Any help is greatly appreciated!

There's only 4 commands shown, all for the frontend. Maybe you're just looking for node server.js for some server file?

Update: the successful command ended up being nodemon run server.js.
